# Is a function-try-block equivalent to a try-catch encompassing whole function?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, exception, boost, try-catch

I'm running a `boost::thread` which is interrupted from somewhere else in my program.

```
auto my_thread = boost::thread(&threadedFunction, this);
```

Is using a `function-try-block` like this

```
void threadedFunction() try {
  // do stuff
} catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
  // handle error
}
```

equivalent to using a try-catch block encompassing the entire function?

```
void threadedFunction() {
  try {
    // do stuff
  } catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

They may not be equivalent, since `my_thread` can be interrupted before the `try` block is entered, and in that case, the program would crash. That being said, I'm not sure if this is possible.

**Are both chunks of code equivalent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not for constructor bodies.

That's why function-try-block [was invented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20purpose%20of%20function,instead%2C%20or%20terminating%20the%20program):

> The primary purpose of function-try-blocks is to respond to an exception thrown from the member initializer list in a constructor by logging and rethrowing, modifying the exception object and rethrowing, throwing a different exception instead, or terminating the program.

### Side note: thread interruption

Boost's thread interruption mechanism is cooperative, not asynchronous (like POSIX signals). That means that, no between `{` and `try {` there cannot be an interruption:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.interruption_point

Even if **were** fully asynchronous, then still it would not make any sense to reason about the "difference" because there would not be any happens-before relationship anyways, so both outcomes could occur in both situations anyways (it's timing dependent regardless).